# ArrayList<E> element shallow copy

Tags: java

I have two `ArrayLists<E>`: `[e0; e1] [  ]`.

I need a shallow copy of `e0` in the second `ArrayList<E>` so that I can modify its value and reflect the changes also in the first `ArrayList<E>`.
If `E` is an `Integer` or a `String` (Immutable) is there a way to change the value without creating a new object?

Comment: "is there a way to change the value without creating a new object?" Even creating a new object doesn't change the value. You can replace one immutable value with another, however.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap immutable objects in a mutable wrapper object? Like a mutable "String decorator" just with setter and getter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If E is an Integer or a String (Immutable) is there a way to change
>   the value without creating a new object

**No.** As you said, `Integer` and `String` are immutable and you only thing you can do is check it, then create new object and save it to the destination list.

Comment: And what if the object is Mutable?

Comment: You mean object in the list: e.g. not `Integer` or `String`, but e.g. `class MyCustom {}`?

Comment: Exactly, I mean this

Comment: Then copy this reference to the destination list (if you need **deep** copy, then you have to create new object).